# Server side vs client side website

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, seo

We have to build a website and we have to chose where to manage the content, in the server (PHP or JSP) or on the client (JavaScript).

This article: http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2358775/seo-strategies-for-javascript-heavy-single-page-applications-or-ajax-sites enlighted me a bit but Im still doubting.

Good **SEO** is the most important thing to achieve. Can anyone relate if **same SEO** results are possible for the same website built client side vs server side? Spiders nowadays (Google mostly) can properly crawl `pushState` and its easier for the developing team to code in JavaScript than any other server-side language but we still dont know how good SEO can be with mostly JavaScript.

In case we end up doing it client-side the server will only answer AJAX calls with JSON so most work will be done on the clients. The webpage is pretty heavy on content and we would like to avoid doing it on server-side to refresh content every time...

But again, SEO is most important overall. JavaScript would manage content faster (and other benefits) but how far can it go against a server-side webpage?

**Edit:** please dont vote to close as opinion based, im looking for those who really experienced this and can relate based on facts, thanks.

Comment: It depends on the content you deliver.

Comment: I was taught to make javascript "unobtrusive" and that also applies to ajax.  We always do testing with javascript turned off to make sure the site is still navigable.  With that approach, we've done a ton of ajax and haven't seen any seo blowback.

Comment: @RightClick you mean by using noscript tag ?

Comment: that may be an approach but I haven't used it for this purpose.  I mean a link will still have a url in the `href` attribute, but then using javascript we add an action listener and have it do an ajax function.  So if javascript is disabled, it still works like a regular link, and that link serves up the content as readable html.

Comment: @AndreiVlad so when would you use client-side, for what type of content?

Comment: @RightClick interesting... that could work, but... the creawlers do render javascript, so why would you bother turning JS off and making sure that content works? There are 0,000001% users that block JS.

Comment: I do it to make sure the content is accessible to the search engine, isn't that what you're asking about ?  Also, if you do things really abstracted, like have a page fetch a json list of posts, then have it load comments for a post based on some post id...the search engine probably won't follow that.  You still want a url to bring you to unique content.  I'm not trying to scare you off from it, it's easy, it just has to be scrape-able and link-able.

Comment: @RightClick sure, thanks for the advice. The links will be allways updated where necessary with pushState, like if you are on /contact-us or /post/how-about-today for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one real SEO issue at stake here: content accessibility. Some search engines don't execute Javascript as part of crawling and indexing. So if your content cannot be accessed with a URL defined in a sitemap without using Javascript, then such content will not be indexed and ranked.

If you don't care about such search engines, then as long as you implement `pushState()` and a complete `sitemap.xml` properly, there is no SEO difference between a server side or client side website.

Comment: all the links will definetly have URL`s ... i mean they wont be all abstract and just show /index every time you view a post or search posts by category or whatever. My idea was to create a js that would act like a map on its own, this JS will listen to all site URL's and ask the server for content depending on url so when for example when "Show latest" button or link is pressed the URL would update to myweb.com/latest and when whatever link is pressed from latest posts it would turn myweb.com/latest/this-selected-post... would this work properly?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Put all the URLs in your sitemap and there won't be any issue with SEO.